# Multiple Tags in one model vs dedicated model

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Would a CustomVision.ai object detection model be as effective with multiple tags as it would be with one?

For example, if I have model A with tags 1, 2 and 3 vs model B with tag 1 and then model C with tag 2, would model A detect tag 1 as well as model B?

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

With enough training data, I believe it can be.

For example, I have a model to detect if there are red or white wine glasses in the image. Most of them have individual tags of the wine, but I did train on one image that had both in it. Here are the results when I did a quick test on another image with both:

[image]

Probably hard to tell which detected object has the associated tag, but you can see that it has pretty high probabilities for both red and white wine.

Hope that helps!